# What is the fastest way to pass a large amount of data from a C++ application to SQLServer Stored Procedure?

Tags: c++, sql-server, xml, performance, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a thousand rows from an xml object in a c++ application to a sqlserver stored procedure in the most efficient way possible.  There is some string processing/conversions that needs to happen to the xml elements before it is inserted into the database.  At the moment we are taking each individual xml node in the C++ application and then calling sqlserver to insert it (and doing this a thousand times).  To improve this I would like to send all 1000 records to sqlserver at the same time.   What is the fastest way to do this?

Also, I have seen that I can send xml straight to a stored procedure, but that would involve me doing a lot of processing to the data before I insert it into the database.  Is it more efficient to process strings in the C++ application and then send it via xml or send it to SQLServer in the unprocessed xml then process/convert the strings or is there another way to pass the data altogether?

Comment: I should also say the slightest performance improvement is desired since this process can be called 100,000 time concurrently.

Comment: Either use BULK INSERT or use a table valued parameter to an insert procedure.

Comment: So it would be quicker to convert the xml on the C++ side to the table value parameter and then pass that over, versus doing the xml parsing and string processing on the sqlserver side?

Comment: It is impossible to state that with certainty because I don't know what your data is or how much processing needs to happen but sql server is not very good at string manipulation. I would be surprised if it was faster doing it in sql. But the absolute best way to know is to build it and try it out both ways.

Comment: Is there any good examples I can follow for using table valued pairs with C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a table-valued parameter, one row for each parameter set. And then use the rows of that parameter to call the stored procedure. Even if you were to submit the rows as a batch to a stored procedure each row would be a separate communication with the server but if you do it as a TVP the driver is able to bundle it into a single round trip (that is, all the data would be sent then the server would start processing, instead of one parameter set getting sent and the result returned for that parameter set).

I don't know about the XML processing, that may well depend on the nature of the required manipulation, that part sounds like a job for profiling.

basically something like:

```
CREATE TYPE ARGS_TABLE TABLE (ID BIGINT, DATA XML);

CREATE PROCEDURE WRAPPER_PROC
@Args ARGS_TABLE READONLY
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ID BIGINT, @Data XML
DECLARE ArgCurs CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, DATA FROM @Args;
OPEN ArgsCurs ;
FETCH NEXT FROM ArgsCurs INTO @ID, @Data
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.REAL_PROC @ID, @Data
FETCH NEXT FROM ArgsCurs INTO @ID, @Data
END
CLOSE ArgsCurs 
    DEALLOCATE ArgsCurs 
END
```

Comment: This is great except cursors suck. Make your procedure receive a table valued parameter and do the inserts as a single insert statement. Doing this in a cursor is going to be hideous with the amount of data the OP is talking about.